# Zeitgeist for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, applications, time-tracking

Does anyone know a application or project for Mac OS X like [Zeitgeist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeitgeist_%28framework%29) for Ubuntu?

> **What is Zeitgeist?**
>
> Zeitgeist is a service which logs the users’ activities and events,
>   anywhere from files opened to websites visited and conversations had.
>
> It makes this information readily available for other applications to
>   use. It is able to establish relationships between items based on
>   similarity and usage patterns.
>
> The service consists:
>
> - Engine
> - Extensions
> - API
> - Dataproviders

(Quote from [http://zeitgeist-project.com](http://zeitgeist-project.com/about/))

Comment: http://www.sniperspymac.com/ kinda, will do what you want but also screen records, might be a bit of overkill.

Comment: @GraemeHutchison You're right! sniperspymac.com is a (little bit) too much!

Comment: Is someone interested in to start a Zeitgeist project for the Mac?

Comment: I think it would be great, but may become difficult as you would need the [Zeitgeist Data-Sources](http://wiki.zeitgeist-project.com/Zeitgeist_Dataproviders) that provide the necessary user activities. And most non-open-source programs aren't likely to provide that.

Comment: @iolsmit You're right. But maybe it is possible to track for that applications only the time in that application. However! I will think about a new project and started a board on Trello for that (https://trello.com/board/zeitgeist-for-mac/4f0ff360fac5fa93090959a1). Everyone is welcome to help and discuss! And I think I will contact with the original Zeitgeist project in the next days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Timing for Mac](http://timingapp.com/) provides at least part of the functionality you are looking for.

> Timing is the best way to keep track of the time you spend with your Mac. Find out where your time goes - without ever having to start a timer again!
>
> Timing automatically tracks which documents you are editing, which applications you use, and the domains of the websites you visit. Afterwards, just drag and drop activities into projects. There are some default categories, but you are free to customize them!